# Am I using RELATED Incorrectly?

Tags: powerbi, dax

I'm getting some strange results creating a very simple calculated column which involves a column from a related table. My calculate column is defined as follows:

```
Exposure = [TotalBilledReceivables] + RELATED(DimCustomer[TotalUnbilledAccruedSales])
```

The Exposure column is a simple sum of TotalBilledReceived + TotalUnbilledAccruedSales from the DimCustomer table. The two tables are properly joined (not many to many). You can see the results are not correct when there is a value in the TotalUnbilledAccruedSales column from the related table. I suspect there is something going on with the RELATED function that I'm not aware of because I am not getting the results I expect.

[image]

Comment: It would be helpful to see your star schema (relevant parts), and some data samples. I'd like to see how the tables are joined (on what keys), and why your dim table contains numeric data like "TotalUnbilledAccruedSales" - usually such data is stored in the fact tables.

Comment: On a separate note, RELATED is affected by a subtle notion called "Table Expansion": https://www.sqlbi.com/articles/expanded-tables-in-dax/

Comment: @Rado - The short answer to your question about why there is a numeric value in a dimension table is this. My fact table is at a sales transaction level and total unbilled accrued sales is at a customer level.

Comment: That's an unusual design - I'd rather store them in a separate fact table and drill across shared dimensions. Calculated columns and usage of RELATED are usually an indication of incorrect star schema design. I have never had a case where they are really needed.

Comment: @Rado - Agreed, it is a bit strange. But is it stranger, or worse design, than having a star schema with multiple fact tables?

Comment: No, not at all. Multiple fact tables are very, very common - one fact table per business process, or per level of aggregation. I usually have 5-10 fact tables in my models.

Comment: @RADO - Thank you. That is useful to know.